# Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already

Tags: ios, xcode

I compile my project using Xcode6 GM on iOS8 GM. When dismissing many view controllers, my app always crashes and the debug area shows:

> "Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already.
>   transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the presentation? "

I have googled and find a similar case and shows the same error:

```
[self.viewController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
        [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

It works fine using Xcode5 and iOS7 . What does the error means? Is iOS8 isn't happy with the "Hack"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by above code ?

Comment: I just ran into the exact same error..

Comment: My assumption this is forcing a view into a single orientation - Thats what i'm doing and i have the same error

Comment: When dismissing many view controllers, if I dismiss them from front to back, my app crashes, but in the opposite order(from back to front), my app works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

> **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion**:If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack.

For example,I have 4 views:A->B->C->D and when I want to dismiss B, I firstly check if C also want to dismiss by using objc_setAssociatedObject to attach/detach a NSString object, and if C wants to dismiss too,then just cancel C's request.Just call dismiss to B.

Answer (score 38):

Are you trying to force a device orientation change?
Anyway, in my opinion you could try to change your current code to:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
    dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

Comment: You can simply dispatch on main queue without zero delay.

Comment: Any news about this? It's a pretty ugly hack, especially if you have a similar implementation in multiple classes!

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated started crashing for us on iOS8.1 with Game Centre Invite views. This fix works a treat!

Comment: This worked for me FYI. It took a great deal of time to find the line number that was causing the error, though.

Comment: @malex - That is simply not true at least in ios 8.3. You have to dispatch with zero delay for some weird reason to hack your way through this bug. This bug is so old but apple doesn't seem to care.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and I found a clean solution avoid using  dispatch_async or dispatch_after.

Simply, as described by the exception, you are trying to dismiss a view controller while the presenting transition is still in progress.
**This means that once the**

```
- presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

**completion block is called, and you invoke the dismiss, the transitioning is not completed.**

Starting from iOS 7 transitioning UIViewController has a new method available

```
- transitionCoordinator
```

The transitionCoordinator gives you the 
chance to enqueue a completion block as soon as the transition completes.

The object returned by the method conforms the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator protocol. Knowing that the solution is really simple.

After the invocation of

```
- presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

the transition coordinator is properly configured by the framework.

Use

```
- animateAlongsideTransition:completion:
```

on it to send the proper completion block.

Here a little code snippet that better explain the solution

```
void(^completion)() = ^() {
    [modalViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

// This check is needed if you need to support iOS version older than 7.0
BOOL canUseTransitionCoordinator = [viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(transitionCoordinator)];

if (animated && canUseTransitionCoordinator)
{
    [viewController presentViewController:modalViewController animated:animated completion:nil];
    [viewController.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        completion();
    }];
}
else
{
    [viewController presentViewController:modalViewController animated:animated completion:completion];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ThirdViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];
UIViewController *VC1 = self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
[VC1 presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: Can you please add some color around your answer. This is not helping anyone.

Comment: sorry i didn't get u.  @Mika

Comment: You just put up a few lines of code. Can you please elaborate on what that code does and why it's a solution.

Comment: it does as same the code in question. Its dismiss current view controller & presenting new view controller.but its overcome that already transtitioning issue.