# How to dismiss modal ViewController from UIAlertcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I show a modal `viewcontroller` on which the user can decide to edit oder delete the presented car.

If the user wants to delete this car I present an `UIAlertController` with alert style to ask if he really wants to delete this car. Everything works fine. But after the user chooses "**Yes**" I am still in the `modal viewcontroller`.

How can I dismiss the modal view after the deletion?

I tried Following Code

```
self.parentViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

in the closure of the ok Action but both didn't worked for me. :(

Comment: how to call dismissviewcontroller view? (Parentview or navigation) share some screen shot or code.

Comment: Did nishith Singh's solution worked?

Comment: no it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside the

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {    //write your code here

 })
```

like that :

```
func showDeleteWarningAndDeleteEntity() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {  

         let deleteController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete car", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) {
        (action) in
    }
    let okACtion = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Destructive) {
        (action) in
        //some network stuff happens here...

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    deleteController.addAction(okACtion)
    deleteController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(deleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     })

}
```

Hope this will works for you

Comment: Dispatching on the main thread has nothing to do with why this worked for you. I presume the fact that you call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated()` is what actually fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes @Mike you are right. Main Thread is not the solution here. It should be the way he dismiss it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to write the code in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {    //write your code here

 })
```

The above code is used to the work in main thread. But here you are already on the main thread.

The issue here is you are calling

```
self.parentViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of it just write

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Because you are presenting `AlertController` on `self` controller so the only one who can dismiss it is `self`

Comment: please check the following link it may be give you the reason you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488918/uialertcontroller-does-not-show-immediately

Comment: Ok dispatch_get_main_queue() always works that is fine. But we should use only when our thread is in background and we want to change UI on main thread, Here in your link he was doing a very long operation and that was always done in background thread and than to make the UI change he did it in dispatch_get_main_queue(). We should be care full to use this main thread block as a long process in Main thread can block the UI and hang your device.

Comment: do you know what code or handling Fox has been implementing for ok button action. And as he already mentioned that  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil),  is not working for him so there is a chance that  in ok button action he must have some code which is executing in background and that's why i SUGGEST him to use dispatch_get_main_queue(). I am not understanding that why are you so rigid with your thinking that you don't want to understand the possible reason for which the given solution work's. Please help yourself if you don't like the solution.

Comment: He never said/mentioned that he tried self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) :) , If he had tried that than he may not have even faced this issue.